# Can I sort output of QUERY and include labels?

Tags: google-sheets, sql-order-by, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I'm trying to format my budget spreadsheet which updates automatically with an attached form. ColA is hidden since it's a timestamp, ColB is the date that the purchase was made, ColC is the category, and ColD is the amount.

I'm trying to sum all amounts within a category and have the output (in ColD) be sorted in descending order, as well as output the labels next to the amounts (in ColC). I have tried using SUMIF, but it's frustrating to use when I want to add multiple categories in specific ranges together. Here's the current code I'm using:

`=QUERY(C3:D64, "SELECT SUM(D) WHERE C <> 'Income' GROUP BY C LABEL SUM(D)''")`

This outputs my data, but without the labels and not in descending order. I can make the order descend in ColE with this code, but again, not labeled:

`=QUERY(D65:D72, "SELECT D ORDER BY D")`

Is there a way to simplify my code and have it output with labels in descending order, including labels for amounts where the output is 0? Here's a screenshot of my current setup.
[image: Spreadsheet screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to include label (Column C), you need to `select` column C in your query.

**Formula order based on column C name in descending order (See Cell F2):**

```
=query(C3:D64,"Select C, sum(D) where C<>'Income' group by C order by C desc label sum(D) ''")
```

**Formula order based on Sum of column D per category in descending order (See Cell I2):**

```
=query(C3:D64,"Select C, sum(D) where C<>'Income' group by C order by Sum(D) desc label sum(D) ''")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Ron! Thank you so much - that second option is exactly what I was looking for. I appreciate how it doesn't include any unnecessary things (like the word "sum" kept showing up before using this formula). I'll look into it and learn why that works! Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to hear that, By the way, If we answered your question, please click the accept button.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [How to accept answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Answer (score 0):

You can add labels anyway, but make sure you keep proper order.
1 SELECT
2 WHERE
3 GROUP BY
4 ORDER BY
5 LABEL
(full list of commands is available in [documentation]: [1](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#select))

I am not sure what you mean by "Labels" -if you mean categories like "groceries, etc. you should use:

```
=QUERY(C3:D64, "SELECT C, SUM(D) WHERE C <> 'Income' GROUP BY C ORDER BY SUM (D) LABEL C 'Category', SUM(D) ''")
```

Sorry if I misanderstood your question